# Assure that parameters passed to a function are unique

Tags: c++

I have a function that looks like this, that calls a function from a third party dll:

```
void f1(const double * const input, double * output){

    // this function will modify output[]
    // I have no knowledge of the implementation of this function, only that it wants
    // 3 doubles as the input parameters, and it will modify the last 3 parameters to
    // pass the result to me.
    call_to_third_party_dll(input[0], input[1], input[2], output[1], output[2], output[3]);

}
```

I am calling this function like this:

```
double value[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

f1(value, value);
// value is now modified
```

This works, and gives the expected results.  (It modifies 'value' as expected.)

I am calling the function with the same pointer for both parameters because it is convenient in the calling context, but I have questioned whether this is safe to do, since I don't know how 'call_to_third_party_dll' handles the parameters.  (for example, it might modify one of the 'output' parameters, then use the modified value as an input for a subsequent calculation.)

I would like to construct f1 in a way that the compiler would complain if 'input' and 'output' are the same thing (like my example).

Is there a way to construct f1 so that it can fail at compile time if 'input' and 'output' are pointing to the same thing?

Note, f1 would not have to use double *.  Whatever is passed will have to resolve to 3 doubles for the input parameters to the third party dll, and 3 doubles for the output of the third party dll.

Comment: Especially if you're actually only using three arguments, I would say in this case your best bet is just to make a defensive copy 100% of the time. Since `input` isn't going to be modified, you could copy `input` to a new array, while leaving `output` alone. Since there's only three doubles, the copy should be dirt cheap. And if you're on an embedded system or something where allocations are costly, you can use a `static` array (or just stack allocate the copy) to reuse storage space or something like that.

Comment: In general, it can't be known in compile time that both parameters point to the same thing.

Comment: What does the declaration of `call_to_third_party_dll` look like? If the first 3 parameters are passed by value there's already a copy made at the call site, so you don't have to worry about aliasing.

Comment: IlCapitano - They are in fact passed by value, so there is actually no doubt that the function will not get blind-sided by the way I'm calling it.  The issue is that when 'output' is modified by the function, so is 'input', when input and output are the same thing.  Then if I try to do things with input and output (after the call), they always look the same when I expect them to be different.  Ultimately refactoring the whole thing is a much better answer (which I did), but the issue made me curious about whether there is a way to guarantee uniqueness of pointer parameters at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have such a check at compile time. There are other options you have though, which are done at runtime.

1. Make a copy of the input. That way, you won't ever get in a situation where you change the same memory. This is of course not very useful if the array is big, but if the array is only 3 doubles, it's no big deal.
2. Compare the pointers. If the pointers points to the same memory, raise an error. You should also make sure that the pointer with the lower address is at least `n * sizeof(type)` bytes away from the pointer with the higher address. I'm unsure if this is a good solution, but it might be a "good-enough" protection for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You change your function to:

```
std::array<double, 3> f1(std::array<double, 3> input){
    std::array<double, 3> output;
    call_to_third_party_dll(input[0], input[1], input[2], output[1], output[2], output[3]);
    return output;
}
```

You can be sure that `input` and `output` are distinct objects.

Comment: I knew when I asked the question that I could refactor (and I did).  I was just curious if there was a way to assure that the const could be protected at compile time by detecting that the same address was passed, etc.